# ReactJs site does not display properly on Github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am trying to deploy a Reactjs website but my website does not show. Here is the link

https://thebestprince.github.io/classy-portfolio/

When I run the website locally on my computer everything thing loads in the browser just fine.

Any ideas why it is not showing up???

Am expecting the webpage to show show in the browser just as it would when I run it locally on my computer

Comment: Have you checked your repo settings that you're serving gh pages from the correct branch https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site